What does the "sm forget" command do?
What does the forget subcommand of the sm command do?
For reference, here's the help output for sm:
usage: sm list-disks [adoptable]
       sm list-volumes [public|private|emulated|stub|all]
       sm has-adoptable
       sm get-primary-storage-uuid
       sm set-force-adoptable [on|off|default]
       sm set-virtual-disk [true|false]

       sm partition DISK [public|private|mixed] [ratio]
       sm mount VOLUME
       sm unmount VOLUME
       sm format VOLUME
       sm benchmark VOLUME
       sm idle-maint [run|abort]
       sm fstrim

       sm forget [UUID|all]

       sm set-emulate-fbe [true|false]

       sm start-checkpoint <num-retries>

       sm supports-checkpoint

       sm unmount-app-data-dirs PACKAGE_NAME PID USER_ID


Some years ago we had a question close to yours: Where can I get more information on the sm tool (command) used in the Terminal

Based on the sm source code the UUID argument is the UUID of a storage volume (=partition?). Not sure which UUIDs can be used. sm list-volumes and sm get-primary-storage-uuid do not return an UUID on my phone. May be you have to use Java API https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager#getStorageVolumes() and the getUUID() on each returned instance.
